# How is the toString method for an array in Java?

Tags: java, string, tostring

say you have a string array like this:

```
String[] someArray = new String[] {"foo", "bar", "bas"};
```

Now I could you this to get a toString representation:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(someArray));
```

But how would be a custom toString method that returns the same string representation?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you asking about how is Arrays.toString implemented?

Comment: yes, thats basically what i would like to know

Comment: It's not a particularly hard function, so it may be a good exercise for you to try and come with the implementation yourself. Start by thinking what it should print (each object's `toString` representation, separated by commas, with an open bracket in front and a closing bracket in back) and then spend a bit of time to figure out how to get each of those parts done. If you want to look at the actual code, [it's online](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.toString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can view the source code for a `Arrays.toString(Object)` by Googling for java source.

I found some here:

[Java Source for Arrays.java in some JDK](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.toString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29)

Go read the code for the toString method there.

Comment: As an addition, there is an archive named **src** inside JDK installation directory, that contains Java source code.

Answer (score 2):

if you pass `Arrays.toString()` an array of custom Objects, it will call the `toString()` methods on those objects.  so if you have an implemented toString method on your objects, `Arrays.toString()` will pick it up